# twig в symfony и без

Tags: symfony, twig

есть шаблон `twig` `<a href="test">{{ search.id }}</a>`, при этом `search.id` (именно `id`) может не существовать. если использовать данный шаблон просто в `twig` подключенный вне `symfony` всё работает. Если же подключить данный шаблон внутри symfony, то выдаётся ошибка `key "id" for array wih keys "name, text" does not exist.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В symfony существует параметр `strict_variables` если она выставить её в false, то она заменит не существующие переменные на null, если в true, будет выкидывать исключение